# Azure Service Bus Entity Throughput

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

As per this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en..., Service Bus can process upto 2000 messages per second per queue/topic. This article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en... says 'This means that the overall throughput of a partitioned queue or topic is no longer limited by the performance of a single message broker or messaging store.' If we create a partitioned queue/topic, I believe it creates 16 partitions internally. My question is: Does the throughput of a partitioned queue/topic rise linearly to 16 x 2000 = 32,000 (approximate) ? Or does the throughput of 2000 msg/sec remain. Can you please point me to any throughput benchmark for partitioned queue/topic? We are currently analyzing a scenario that needs a very high throughput topic. Guidance on this question will be really helpful.

This question has been posted on the Azure site also, at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-performance-improvements/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance will vary based on a number of things. For example, many advanced features (like duplicate detection, sessions, transactions, etc,) will add overhead therefore decreasing throughput. In case you want to benchmark this yourself, try running this performance sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-messaging-performance

Also, because basic/standard are shared tenant models the performance you get today, may be different from the performance you get tomorrow. In addition you may not see linear scale as some nodes can be more busy than others.

For true predictability, premium is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you @JTaub. So what i understand is that the throughput will be higher than 2000 messages/second/queue using partitioned queues/topics. It may not be exactly linear due to the sharing of resources and use of features, which is fair enough.

Comment: Using this tool with a standard plan I don't get over 14 msg/s in the best cases. I got the same results with my own benchmarking tool some weeks ago. I'm using the default ServiceBus configuration with a Queue. I didn't test the Premium plan because of the price, but I would expect better performance for Standard ServiceBus.