# How to get better performance with Azure ServiceBus Standard plan

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I don't manage to get over 14 msg/second with the Azure ServiceBus Standard Plan. I'm running some benchmark tests with the [Azure-Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091733/azure-service-bus-entity-throughput) tool that I found in this [question](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-messaging-performance):

The test is done with a ServiceBus resource with a single Queue and all default configurations:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I read this correctly, you've got the maximum concurrency of one (`MaxInflightReceives`) with 5 receivers (`ReceiverCount`). Increasing concurrency and enabling prefetch on the clients will increase the overall throughput. But,

1. Testing should be done within the same Azure data centre. If you're testing from a local machine, you're introducing a substantial latency that cannot be avoided.
2. The receive mode used is `PeekLock`. It is slower than `ReceiveAndDelete`. Not suggesting to switch, but this needs to be taken into consideration as you're trading throughput for safety by using `PeekLock`.
3. The standard tier has a cap on the number of operations per second. In addition to that, your namespace is deployed in a shared environment with entities scattered in various deployment containers. Performance **will** vary and cannot be guaranteed. If you want to have a guaranteed throughput, use Premium SKU.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will set up a test as you are proposing.